# Php - Mail subscribe Form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have 2 files:

1. Index.html
2. sendmail.php

The code is working fine, except I'm trying to echo the message on the same page without flipping to another or getting redirected automatically to index.html.

I've tried many options without success. I need some help - I'm new to php.

Here is the code:

Index.html:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="php/sendmail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email...">
<button type="submit" class="btn_email">Subscribe</button>
</form>'
```

sendmail.php:

```
<?php
$to = "info@mywebsite.com"; // my email address 
$from = "no-reply@mywebsite.com"; // from (my email)

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];


if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{ 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
{
$filename=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    echo 'Your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ') has been added to our mailing list!';
}
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
} 
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to echo the message on same page"* - Not with an `.html` file extension you won't, not unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to use AJAX. AJAX allows server side code to be executed with the page reloading or being redirected.

The simplest way to do it would be to use JQUERY.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

var email = $('input[type="email"]').val();

var queryString = "email="+email;

$.ajax({

    url : "php/sendmail.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : queryString,
    dataType : "html",
    success : function(output) {

        $('body').append("<p>"+output+"</p>");

    }

});
```

});

You should also save index.html as index.php.

Also make sure you include JQUERY on the page. You can do this by putting : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`  anywhere in index.php

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply . . however, should I add this script along the side with my previous php code . . because trying to execute it .. nothing happens.

Comment: I have re-saved index file as php . .

Comment: I forgot to prevent default on the form submit. This will stop the form submitting as it usually would on click of the submit button. Also maybe you haven't included JQUERY? I just tested the above code with your form and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// display form if user has not clicked submit
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
?>

<form class="form-inline" action="php/sendmail.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn_email">Subscribe</button>
</form>`

<?php 
}


else { 
// the user has submitted the form
//enter your php code here 
}
```